# Subjunctive Conjugation Rules: Is desire or hope all that's required to trigger usage?

Tags: verbos, subjuntivo, conjugación

"Ojalá que llueva café."  There are many examples like this that, for me, clearly call for the subjunctive.  However, is that ***always*** the rule?  Must I merely be expressing a desire or hope?  Is it just that simple?  Or are there other contexts where the subjunctive is called for?  Let's take a few examples:

"Quiero que vengas."
"Me gustaría que vengas."
(And even though this is not about verb tense ...)
"Queria que vinieras."

Would there ever be a context in which the indicative conjugation (ie. "vienes", "viniste") would still work but have a different nuance?
Any examples where subjunctive usage is more hidden or complicated than the "rule" I laid out above?  I can't remember specific examples at the moment but there are times when I run into scenarios where I'm not confident if the subjunctive is called for or not.

Answer (score 3):

This is a difficult question. I am not aware of any exhaustive reference of cases where both indicative and subjunctive verb forms are possible. What follows is a partial answer, where I will list some guidelines and interesting cases where both moods are possible, with or without a change in meaning.

First, as you say, the subjunctive mood is always used with expressions of wishes, hopes and often requests like 'ojalá', 'deseo que', 'espero que', 'pido que', 'tengo la esperanza/el deseo de que', etc. In these cases, only the subjunctive is correct. Whether you use a present subjunctive or a past subjunctive depends on the tense of the main verb: present subjunctive with present and future forms and past subjunctive with past and conditional forms, the *pretérito perfecto* being a fringe area where both can be acceptable.

```
Pediré que vengas.
Pido que vengas.
He pedido que vinieras/-ses.
He pedido que vengas.
Pedí que vinieras/-ses.
Pedía que vinieras/-ses.
Había pedido que vinieras/-ses.
```

We can also use the perfect subjunctive forms in the second part, with a similar shift in tenses when the time frame is in the past: 'Espero que hayas triunfado', 'esperaba que hubieras/-ses triunfado'.

But when we think about different verbs, we start to find uses that diverge from the general pattern. I've already mentioned how we can use both a present and a past subjunctive after 'he pedido que', which wouldn't work with 'he esperado que' (at least in my variety of Spanish). A similar verb is 'confiar en algo'. But in this case, we can put the verb in the second part in the future or conditional tense, with the same meaning as a subjunctive. Examples:

```
Confiaré en que la ayuda llegue a tiempo.
Confiaré en que la ayuda llegará a tiempo.
Confío en que la ayuda llegue a tiempo.
Confío en que la ayuda llegará a tiempo.
He confiado en que la ayuda llegara/-se a tiempo.
He confiado en que la ayuda llegaría a tiempo.
He confiado en que la ayuda llegue a tiempo.
He confiado en que la ayuda llegará a tiempo.
Confié (confiaba, había confiado) en que la ayuda llegara/-se a tiempo.
Confié (confiaba, había confiado) en que la ayuda llegaría a tiempo.
```

'Tener la confianza en que' works in exactly the same way and you can use the perfect subjunctive forms in the second part, of course ('confío en que la ayuda haya/habrá llegado a tiempo', 'confiaba en que la ayuda hubiera/-se/habría llegado a tiempo', etc.).

We find yet another interesting case in verbs like 'suponer' or 'imaginar' in the imperative forms, like 'supón que', 'imagina que' or 'supongamos que', 'imaginemos que'. Here, we tend to use the present indicative for things that can realistically happen, while the past subjunctive evokes the idea that we're stating a counterfactual thought experiment, imagining something that is improbable or untrue. Consider the following examples:

```
Supongamos que x es un número irracional.
Supongamos que Suiza fuera/-se un país pobre.
Imagina que consigues el trabajo.
Imagina que pudiéramos/-semos volar.
```

Of course, sometimes both versions work, depending on your level of optimism: '¡imagina que nos toca la lotería!', ¡imagina que nos tocara/-se la lotería!'. Actually, this difference in nuance is also possible in English, where we can say 'imagine/suppose we win the lottery!' or 'imagine/suppose we won the lottery!'.

Another case I can think of where both indicative and subjunctive can be used is that of sentences introduced by 'quizá(s)'. Here the present subjunctive is equivalent to a future indicative when we would use a future in English.

```
Quizás tengamos suerte.
Quizás tendremos suerte.
Maybe we will be lucky.
```

If we say that maybe something has happened in the past, then we can use a *pretérito perfecto* in either indicative or subjunctive form, with no change in meaning.

```
Quizás hayamos tenido suerte.
Quizás hemos tenido suerte.
Maybe we have been lucky.
```

To complicate matters even more, in the colloquial language we tend to use 'a lo mejor' much more often than 'quizá(s)', but we always use the present or the *pretérito perfecto* in this case, so the above sentences can also be rendered, more colloquially but without any change in meaning, as:

```
A lo mejor tenemos suerte.
A lo mejor hemos tenido suerte.
```

In Spain, we never use the subjunctive with 'a lo mejor', even though there is no clear logical reason why this is so.

There are also verbs that carry different meanings depending on whether they are followed by a clause with an indicative or a subjunctive verb. For example, 'entiendo que vienes' means 'I assume you are coming' whereas 'entiendo que vengas' means 'I understand why you are coming'. 'Dijeron que venías' means 'they said you were coming', and 'dijeron que vinieras/-ses' 'they told you to come'. [This link](https://svfspanish.com/indicativo-vs-subjuntivo-con-verbos-de-doble-construccion/?cn-reloaded=1) lists a few such cases.

There are probably many more similar cases.

Answer (score 2):

El subjuntivo en ocasiones puede ser un problema, aparte de deseos y esperanzas, el subjuntivo suele utilizarse bastante en narrativa, también en oraciones de relativo, por ejemplo, cuando el hablante desconoce la existencia del antecedente. "*Busco un hombre que tenga una buena posición*" o cuando el antecedente no existe o es escaso "*Hay poca gente que hable mejor que tu el español*". Por otro lado, se utiliza el modo indicativo cuando el hablante conoce el antecedente. "*Busco un hombre que habla español*".

La forma menos utilizada en subjuntivo el el "***futuro***", tanto simple como perfecto, ya que normalmente solo se usa en el ámbito legal. "Los que mataren a una persona...".

Una forma particular es el "***modo yusivo***", el cual se utiliza para expresar un mandato o deseo de algo que ha sucedido en el pasado. "*Dirás que él hubiera debido vivir*".

---

**Para facilitar el uso del Subjuntivo es necesario conocer al menos cinco estructuras básicas;**

**1 - Siempre y Cuando + Subjuntivo**

/ Puedes venir a la fiesta **siempre y cuando traigas** una pizza.

/ Su hija sacará sobresaliente **siempre y cuando mantenga** estas notas.

/ **Siempre y cuando me digas** la verdad nuestra relación irá bien.

/ Este año podremos viajar **siempre y cuando se respeten** las normas Covid-19.

**2 - Valoraciones con Subjuntivo**

/ Me parece bien/mal que + subjuntivo. Ejem Me parece bien que **hables** de él.

/ Me parece lógico/razonable que + subjuntivo. Ejem Me parece lógico que **vengas**.

/ Me parece correcto/injusto que + subjuntivo. Ejem Me parece injusto que **sea** así.

/ No me parece normal que + subjuntivo. Ejem No me parece normal que **haya** saltado.

/ No me parece bien/mal + subjuntivo. Ejem No me parece bien que **venga**.

**3 - Cuando + Subjuntivo**

Se utiliza cuando + presente del subjuntivo, solo cuando queremos expresar algo en el futuro. Si usamos cuando + presente del indicativo, es para expresar algo que normalmente hacemos a diario o frecuente en algún momento.

Cuando + presente simple (del indicativo)

/ Cuando hace frío siempre enciendo el radiador.

/ Cuando más trabajo tengo es cuando más ganas tengo de salir a correr.

**Cuando** + **presente del subjuntivo**

/ **Cuando llegue** el invierno voy a ir a la montaña todos los días.

/ **Cuando tenga** 2.000.000 de seguidores fundaré una religión.

/ **Cuando consiga** hablar español, viajaré por la Costa Alicantina.

**4 - Con verbos como "gustar", "agobiar", "alegrar", "asustar", "desagradar", "disgustar", "divertir", "doler", "encantar"... + Subjuntivo**

Con estos verbos se combinan bien el modo subjuntivo, siempre y cuando hablemos de un sujeto diferente u otra persona distinta:

/ Me **gusta** mucho que **seas** agradable con mi madre.

/ Me **asusta** mucho que **bebas** tanta ginebra.

/ Me **encantan** que **vengan** a casa mis amigos con sus novias.

/ Me **agobia** que **estés** todo el día llamándome al móvil.

**5 - Antes/Después de que + Subjuntivo**

Esta estructura suele utilizarse siempre con el subjuntivo

/ **Antes** de que **llegues** a casa pasa yo ya me he ido.

/ **Antes** de que **pidas** matrimonio, consúltalo con tu abogado.

/ **Después** de que nos **vayamos** se irán de fiesta.

**P.D.** Aquí te dejo un video en que te explican estas estructuras. Si lo necesitas, puedes darle al botón de los subtítulos y ayudarte en la comprensión. Espero te haya servido.

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTOGRbpk8I4

Comment: Cuidado, " a parte" ≠ "aparte"

Comment: OK, Gracias por estar atento!